# Python Atom Hydrogen, stepping through code line by line, or all at once

Tags: python, class, atom-editor, hydrogen

I just installed Hydrogen module into Atom so I can get user input into Python.
How can I run the code using hydrogen without going line by line?
The only reason I installed this program so I can input data using the input() python command.
I am going line by line but as soon as I instantiate one of my python classes, it says classname NOT FOUND.
How can I make hydrogen read the class name which is in the same file but not in the main() module?

Comment: There is an option to  "run cell". Have you tried that?

Comment: Thx, I tried run all, and it worked

Comment: if i post that as an answer will you accept it so I get the points?

Comment: please ignore the above comment. i see that wasn't my answer.

Answer (score 0):

**ctrl-alt-Shift-Enter** will *Run All* in Atom on Windows. This is a bit better than *Run Cell*
because running the cell will stop if you have any markers set up to define cells, which you can look into in the Hydrogen docs: https://nteract.gitbooks.io/hydrogen/docs/Usage/Cells.html